# I have a WSDL link.Using nusoap how can i communicate? what is wrong in my Code?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, nusoap

```
http://tunnel.nno.dk/NNService/1.0/NNService.wsdl
```

This is the wsdl link.I am using nusoap

```
require_once('nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');

$wsdl="http://tunnel.nno.dk/NNService/1.0/NNService.wsdl";
$client=new soapclient($wsdl, 'wsdl');

$param=array('phone' => '99999999','username' => 'test');

$result = $client->call('lookupSubscribers', $param);
```

What is wrong in my Code?It is not working.
I am just validating my telephone no.

I am getting this error message

```
<errorMessage xsi:type="xsd:string"> not access this service from IP (176.9.60.16) with the username () </ errorMessage>
```

But the ipaddress is not a problem,because with soap ui it is working ..but with nusoap it is not working..What is wrong in my code.

Comment: How can you tell that it is not working?

Comment: I am getting error message  <errorMessage xsi:type="xsd:string">Ikke adgang til denne service fra IP(176.9.60.16) med brugernavn ()</errorMessage>   but when i used with soap UI it is working

Comment: Okay you should put that error message into your question (edit it), that's important. And if you can, add a translation of that error message in english as well.

Comment: <errorMessage xsi:type="xsd:string"> not access this service from IP (176.9.60.16) with the username () </ errorMessage>

Comment: You need to tell the endpoint the username. Obviously the way you do it right now does not work out because the username is blank in the errormessage.

Comment: no i have given the username correctly.It is working with SOAP UI.

Comment: Obviously SOAP UI is *not* nusoap. I assume you missed to add the many other parameters. See http://services.w3.org/xslt?xslfile=http://tomi.vanek.sk/xml/wsdl-viewer.xsl&amp;xmlfile=http://tunnel.nno.dk/NNService/1.0/NNService.wsdl&amp;transform=Submit

Comment: Found it....                                                                 Wrong =>$param=array('phone' => '99999999','username' => 'test');
 Right   => $param= '<Question_1 xsi:type="typ:SearchQuestion" xmlns:typ="http://tunnel.nno.dk/NNService/1.0/Types"><phone xsi:type="xsd:string">999999999</phone><username xsi:type="xsd:string">test</username></Question_1>';                                                      Now it is working Great..Ihave to pass in Xml Format.....              Thank you very much hakre ....May Jesus Bless You Abundantly

Comment: Checkout the nusoap documentation, you should be able to call it w/o XML as well. And please keep Jesus away from me ;)

Comment: And add your solution as an answer below (yes that works!). You can accept it later so your question becomes marked as solved and the info is online if someone else is running into the same problem as you did.

Comment: Unfortunately i can add it..because it is saying i need to wait another 7 hours for that...Why cant you add this answer man..???????I will approve the answer..You add the answer below...

Comment: then just wait for seven hours and add it then. it won't run away ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it....

Wrong =>

```
$param=array('phone' => '99999999','username' => 'test');
```

Right =>

```
$param= '<Question_1 xsi:type="typ:SearchQuestion" xmlns:typ="tunnel.nno.dk/NNService/1.0/Types"><phone xsi:type="xsd:string">999999999</phone><username xsi:type="xsd:string">test</username></Question_1>';
```

Now it is working Great..I have to pass in Xml Format.....